# Infinite render caused by child component taking props from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component which fetches data and then passes props to a child child component.
This causes and infinite re-render caused by child component. I wonder what is happening
Here is how my code looks like

```js
const Page: FunctionComponent<pageProps> = (): JSX.Element => {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<userInfoStruct>();
    const [data, setData] = useState<any>();

    useEffect(() => {

       // fetch info from localstore
       setUserInfo(dataFromLocalStorage);
       fetchSomeData(); // do stuff... and setData(fetchResult)
    }, [userInfo]);

    return (
     <div>
       <ButtonsAndStuff />
       <DisplayData data={data} />
     </div>
    )
};
```

My child component looks something like this

```js
const DisplayData: FunctionComponent<displayDataProps> = ({ data }): JSX.Element => {
    const data_: Array<any> = data.map(d =>  (d.value))

    return (
     <div>
       {data_.map(i => {
         return (
          <div>
           {i}
          </div>
         )
       })}
     </div>
    )
};
```

Unfortunately my component continually re-renders and react says the problem comes from my child component specifically at the level of taking props in the child i.e this line

```js
const DisplayData: FunctionComponent<displayDataProps> = ({ data }): JSX.Element => {/*... */};
```

I don't know what is going wrong at this point.

***temp***

```js
useEffect(() => {
        let userName: string = localStorage.getItem("userName");
        let user: string = localStorage.getItem("user");

        if (userName === undefined || user === undefined) {
            return;
        } else {
            setUserInfo({ user: user, userName: userName });
            setIsAuth(true);
        }

        /*  */
        if (blogData.length < 1) {
            fetchBlogData(user, blogIndex).then(result => {
                console.log(result)
               
                setBlogData(result);
            });
        } else {
            return;
        }
        /*  */
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem doesn't seem to be caused by your child component, but by this part of your code:

```js
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<userInfoStruct>();
const [data, setData] = useState<any>();

useEffect(() => {

    // fetch info from localstore
    setUserInfo(dataFromLocalStorage);
    fetchSomeData(); // do stuff... and setData(fetchResult)
}, [userInfo]);
```

Assuming that `dataFromLocalStorage` isn't just a string/number, it's probably a unique array/object every time. You alter `userInfo`, which therefore makes the `[userInfo]` dependency list change, therefore re-executing your effect, ad infinitum.

If you only want to execute the effect once, use `[]` as dependency list.

Comment: Trying that does not fix my problem. It also seem to be at the level of getting info from localStorage. I am using nullish coalescing i.e `const user = localStorage.getItem('user') ?? undefined // get the info`

Comment: @frozenByte the only possible loop I see is the `useEffect` getting triggered (nearly) every render due to `userInfo` changing. Unless you're somehow calling `setData`/`setUserInfo` constantly.

Comment: `setUserInfo` is called only once inside the `useEffect` and i have changed the dependency to be an empty array now. Unfortunately it will still render without data sometimes while when it actually fetches the data, an infinite loop is caused

Comment: @frozenByte then I suggest showing more of the original code inside `useEffect`. Or checking whether the props passed to `Page` often change, e.g. if the re-rendering actually happens higher up in the component tree.

Comment: ```typescript 
useEffect(() => {
        let userName: string = localStorage.getItem("userName");
        let user: string = localStorage.getItem("user");
        if (userName !== undefined || user !== undefined){
            setUserInfo({ user: user, userName: userName });
            setIsAuth(true);
        }

        if (blogData.length < 1) {
            fetchBlogData(user, blogIndex).then(result => {
                setBlogData(result);
                blogDate = result.map(c => ({ value: c.date}));
            });
        }
    }, []);```

Comment: @frozenByte You can edit your original question with the updated code instead.

Comment: Done!
Above under temp

Comment: Hmm weird. With the `[]` dependency list, that effect should only run once, even when the component re-renders. Unless the parent component somehow causes it to be a brand new component every time. Not sure what's causing the render loop.